# Custom template for Query Exceptions in Laravel

Tags: laravel

When there's a database related error page, outputing data like:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
    SQLSTATE[42S22]:
```

Is there a way to redirect all these custom errors to one custom template?

I checked [methods of Route class](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html), couldn't figure an exact solution.

Comment: you have a `app/Exceptions/Handler` where inside there is a `render` method, where you can check whether the app is a `QueryException` and if it is, use a your custom view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle this in your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

```php
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof QueryException)) {
        return response()->view('errors.query-exception', [], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

You need to check if the `$exception` is an instance of `Illuminate\Database\QueryException` so you can render your own error page.